# Bitwise devision? (Changing formats of ints)

Tags: java, colors, bit-manipulation

I'm using Java. I have an integer where:

> Bits 24-31 are alpha, 16-23 are red,
>   8-15 are green, 0-7 are blue.

I would like to change this to an int where:

> Bits 5-7 are red, 2-4 are green, and 0-1 are blue.

I'm not sure how best to go about this. (Obviously, some fidelity in representable colors will be lost. This is acceptable, as long as it's proportionate, so the colors look roughly the same.)

Can I just divide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you

```
int argb =
// extract the colours. 
int red = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (argb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = argb & 0xFF;

// reduce the number of bits.
red >>= 5;
green >>= 5;
blue >>= 6;

// build the new value
int rgb2 = (red << 5) + (green << 2) + blue;
```

Comment: The purpose of `& 0xFF` is to get all 8-bits before you do the conversion. The simplest approach is to drop the lower bits (as @Alnitak does) but you might want to round the result or something else. `argb` is short for alpha/red/green/blue. If you want to change this value you can assign it on the last line instead of `rgb2`

Comment: You should be getting 233.  Thats what I get when I run the code. -1355953 is 11111111
11101011
01001111
01001111 in binary, if you skip the first byte and take the first 3 bits, first 3 bits and first 2 bits you get 111 010 01 which is 233.

Answer (score 1):

no. you need to do bitshifting and masking.

For instance, to get red, you want 3 bits. So you need to grab the most significant bits of red which are bits 23, 22, and 21.

so

```
int red = ((color >> 21) & 0x07); // gets the top 3 bits of the src red, and put in bottom of int
int newColor = red << 4; // shift back up to the new color
```

you'd have to do that for each component, and or (|) the values into the new color

Answer (score 0):

For each component, shift bits and mask out the least significant bits.

In long hand, if `col` is your original colour then:

```
r = (col >> 21) & 0x07; // bits 21 - 23
g = (col >> 13) & 0x07; // bits 13 - 15
b = (col >>  6) & 0x03; // bits  6 -  7
```

and your new value is:

```
(r << 5) | (g << 2) | b
```

Or, to roll it all into one expression:

```
rgb = (col & 0xe00000) >> 16 | (col & 0xe000) >> 11 | (col & 0xc0) >> 6;
```